# access 365 combo box selection adding a record to rowSource

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I have a two column combo box on a form. The rowsource is set to a two column table. The table is GenderRef there are two fields; GenderSaid and Gender. GenderRef is related by GenderSaid to my People table. GenderRef has two records; GenderSaid = 1 and Gender = Male, GenderSaid = 2 and Gender = Female. When I run the form and select  for example: Male from the combobox drop down then proceed to the next record, the GenderRef table has a new record added, GenderSaid = 3 and Gender = Male. I have run the cleanup and repair database utility. I have tried other properties. I have tried to change the relationship and even delete it but with the same result. I would use a value list but I will also be adding a few other reference combo boxes with more than two items in the list and want to get it right with the simplest one. The only VBA code I have runs an update query to the People table updating People.GenderSaid. I have commented out the entire VBA sub and still get a new record in GenderRef.

Comment: it sounds like your combobox control source is set to the GenderRef Table.  If there is any value in your combobox control source delete it and uncomment the vba.

Comment: Why would you need VBA to run UPDATE action on People table? Bind form to People table. Don't include GenderRef in form RecordSource.

Comment: @mazoula I tried your suggestion but it didn't bring in Male or Female per the assigned GenderSaid value in the People table. It did work to not add a record to the GenderRef table

Comment: @June7 it is bound to a multi-table query the GenderRef table contains the Male/Female Gender field. I thought it should update as well but it doesn't. I think my relationships are not right somehow.

Comment: Why are you using a multi-table record source? Bind form to People table. People table needs a field to save selected GenderRef GenderSaid value.

Comment: I just created a value list in my form, did away with the reference table and changed the people table field to be a text box. The form updates the table just fine now.

Comment: @June7 sorry it's the form itself that has a multi-table. People, Address, phone, and email plus join tables between each since they have many-to-many relationships

Comment: I know that. My point is that is probably unnecessary and causing confusion. If you do include those related tables, don't allow any of their fields to be edited via this form. Lock textboxes and set TabStop to no.